# How to translate javascript-files in Pylons

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, translation, pylons

We're making an application by using Pylons and JQuery. We have used standard way of making translations, but it doesn't quite work with javascript.

The awkwardness of js-translation methods is that we should make duplicate processes for selecting languages etc.

Is there a proper support in Pylons for javascript-translations?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is to use the pylons gettext to generate your own javascript string ids like this:

html template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var i18n_strings = {
      hello_world = '${ugettext('Hello World!')}',
      goodbye_world = '${ugettext('Goodbye World!')}',
      enter_name = '${ugettext('Enter Name:')}'
   };
</script>
```

now in your javascript:

```
$('#some-elem').html( i18n_strings.hello_world );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using that solution with Pylons and ExtJS, but i think you can easily, change JS function for your needs..

In Pylons controller i have method which exports all translations (you need polib for this - http://code.google.com/p/polib/):

```
import polib
from pylons.i18n import get_lang

...

## method in conttroller class
@jsonify
def get_trans(self):
    def get_trans():
        items = polib.mofile(os.path.join(config['pylons.paths']['root'], 'i18n/%s/LC_MESSAGES/app.mo' % get_lang()[0]))
        return [{'name': item.msgid, 'value': item.msgstr} for item in items]
    return {'translations' : get_trans()}
```

JavaScript part:

```
lang_store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: '/lang/get',
    root: 'translations',
    id: 'name',
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['name', 'value'],
});

gettext = _ = function(_key) {
    try {
        return lang_store.getById(_key).data.value
    } catch(e) {
        return _key + "**"
    }
}
```

Now you can use "gettext(STRING)" or "_(STRING)" function in JS and you'll get translated string, if there will be no translation, you'll get something like UNTRANSLATED_STRING** (with asterisks at the end) .